# Outlook 2007 "remember my password" does not remember the domain

Tags: microsoft-outlook, domain

When I enter my username/password on Outlook 2007, it doesn't log in unless I type

```
DOMAIN\userId
```

If I click "Remember my password", the next time the dialog **doesn't work to log me in** because it reduces my userId to just

```
userId
```

Stripping off the domain.

How can I make it remember the domain?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is not retaining the credentials due to your Outlook profile been corrupted.

Create a new [Outlook profile](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;290684).

Also, Outlook shouldn't be prompting for credentials.

1.Make sure you are not locked out of the system. 
2.Password is not expired.
3.The profile security is not set to prompt for logon credentials.

To Resolve:

-Tools>Account Settings>Change>More settings>Security>unchek Always prompt for   credentials>Apply and restart Outlook.

4.MS Exchange could be connecting via HTTP.

To Resolve:
  -Tools>Account Settings>Change>More settings>Connection>Under the Outlook Anywhere section, make sure 'Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP' is unchecked.